# Compiler error with vector of deque of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code fails to compile on gcc 5.3 with compiler error complaining that the copy constructor of the unique_ptr is somehow invoked. Can someone explain why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <deque>

using Foo = std::deque<std::unique_ptr<int>>;                                   


void foo() {                                                                    
  std::vector<Foo> a;                                                           
  a.emplace_back();   // this fails to compile                                                             
}
```

The key line in the compiler error is:

`gcc-4.9.2/include/c++/4.9.2/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’ { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }`

Comment: Oh yeah, this is a mess.

Comment: You should include `<vector>` and `<deque>`, not `<queue>`. Not that it matters here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Fixed. BTW, if we replace std::deque with std::queue, the code failed to compile for the same compiler error.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet. Added the error message to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `vector::emplace_back` needs to handle reallocation.
- on `vector` reallocation, the existing elements are *moved* if either

  - they cannot be copied (as determined by `std::is_copy_constructible`); or
  - their move constructor is `noexcept`.

  otherwise they are copied. This is to maintain the strong exception safety guarantee.
- `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<int>>`'s move constructor is not `noexcept` (depending on the implementation, it may need to allocate memory).
- `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<int>>` can be copied according to `std::is_copy_constructible`, because that only checks if there is a constructor with the right signature, not whether the body of said constructor will actually compile.
- `vector::emplace_back` therefore attempts to copy it.
- the compiler blows up.

Comment: Could this be considered a defect in the language? Because this is absurd.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Last time I poked about, it had something to do with stateful allocators. You can't tell at compile time if two allocators are equal, so you don't know at compile time if you can move or have to copy.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's a separate beast (move assignment).

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Hard to fix because of custom allocator `construct`s, I think. You can't SFINAE on just `is_copy_constructible` etc. because `construct` can mutilate the arguments.

Comment: @T.C. Thank you so much! The explanation makes a lot of sense. I have to say this behavior is very surprising and the reasoning is very subtle, especially the point that deque move constructor is not noexcept.